# Brick Displacement Map Giving Jagged Vertical Edges

Tags: texturing, displacement

I am struggling to get displacement mapping to work for a brick wall. It's coming out with a bunch of vertical lines in the displacement like this:

[image: Jagged Edge displacement]

I successfully did this in a previous project, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I tried starting a new project and repeating the process with just the default cube, and it still gives me this result. Here are my modifier settings for the wall (I subdivided the wall multiple times before the modifiers):

[image: Modifier settings]

And the shader:

[image: Brick Shader Settings]

What do I need to do to get the displacement modifier working correctly?

Comment: Hi :). You probably need to switch the Displace modifier to UV coordinates.

Comment: That fixed it! If you turn your comment into an answer then I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the *Displace modifier* to UV coordinates.

1. And
2. it's
3. Done.

[image]